# Node/Express - POST request to receive zip from remote server, pass back to client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, post

So here's the architecture overview of my setup:

- PEBKAC
- AngularJS Frontend
- NodeJS/Express Middleman
- Spring/Hibernate API
- MySQL Database

Right now in the Spring API, I have an API call to generate a zip file dynamically. This call returns a chunked binary stream.

What I need to do is catch this stream in Node/Express and pass it back to the AngularJS frontend.

User journey is that the user checks off list of items to export, clicks the button to confirm export, and an http request is made to Node. Node then sends a request to Spring, which returns the stream, and sends the result back to AngularJs.

Don't need any lectures on how we shouldn't have Node/Express or Spring - the architecture is going to change, and this is a lot of legacy code right now.

Current Express request to Spring:

```
exports.zipRequest = function(path, postBody, onResult) {

    var options = {
        host: host,
        port: port,
        path: springContext + path,
        method: 'POST',
        encoding: 'binary',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/zip'
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res){

        var output = '';
        res.setEncoding('binary');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            onResult(res.statusCode, output);
        });


    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        req.end();
    });

    req.write(postBody.toString());
    req.end();
};
```

Current Node API:

```
exports.exportSessions = function(req, res) {

    var dataset = req.user.dataset;
    var id = req.params.id;

    var arr = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    var today = new Date();
    var filename = today.toISOString();
    filename = filename.replaceAll("-","_");
    filename = filename.replaceAll(":","_");
    filename = filename.replace(".","_");

    var path = '/Export/dataset/'+dataset+'/exportZip/';

    api.zipRequest(path, arr, function(statusCode, result) {

        if(statusCode != 200) {

            console.log(statusCode);
            console.log(result);
            res.send(statusCode, "Problem from backend API");

        } else {

            if (result != null || typeof result != 'undefined') {

                res.type('application/zip')
                res.attachment(filename+'.zip');
                res.send(result, 'binary');

            } else {

                res.send(statusCode, "Undefined Result" + result);

            }
        }
    });

};
```

Looking to figure out how to get the client browser to save the returned file - as I can see the binary string fine, and I'm setting all the headers necessary. I've tried everything from creating a buffer in express and returning that, to `res.write()` in the Node API response and nothing seems to work.

EDIT:

So I've managed to get Express to Pipe the zip back to the client in its entirety using the following:

```
    var req = http.request(options, function (res){

        var today = new Date();
        var filename = today.toISOString();
        filename = filename.replaceAll("-","_");
        filename = filename.replaceAll(":","_");
        filename = filename.replace(".","_");

        res.setEncoding('binary');

        res.pipe(onResult);
};
```

and in Node:

```
exports.exportSessions = function(req, res) {

    var dataset = req.user.dataset;
    var id = req.params.id;

    var arr = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    var today = new Date();
    var filename = today.toISOString();
    filename = filename.replaceAll("-","_");
    filename = filename.replaceAll(":","_");
    filename = filename.replace(".","_");

    var path = '/Export/dataset/'+dataset+'/exportZip/';
    res.type('application/zip')
    res.attachment(filename+'.zip');
    return api.zipRequest(path, arr, res);
}
```

I can see in developer console that the entire file streams to the client (browser), and the response headers are as follows:

```
access-control-allow-headers:Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token
access-control-allow-methods:POST, GET
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:private, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
content-disposition:attachment; filename="2016_11_16T09_34_50_976Z.zip"
content-type:application/zip
Date:Wed, 16 Nov 2016 09:34:51 GMT
expires:-1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Still no dice on getting a save prompt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Hopefully this gives a rather in-depth answer to anybody looking to hold an initial request, and pass back the response from a secondary.

I solved this by using the npm [request](https://github.com/request/request) module, and modifying my Node API call from a POST to a GET:

```
var request = require('request');

exports.exportSessions = function(req, res, next) {

    var dataset = req.user.dataset;
    var arr = decodeURIComponent(req.query.ids);

    var path = '/Export/dataset/'+dataset+'/exportZip/';
    console.log('Exporting Data '+arr);

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://' + api.host + ':' + api.port + api.springContext + path,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/zip'
        },
        json: true,
        body: JSON.parse(arr)
    };

    request.post(options).pipe(res)
}
```

and changing my Angular request to simply open a new window with the get URL:

```
$scope.exportData = function() {
    var ids = $scope.sessions.selected.map(function(ses){
        return ses.id;
    });
    var pars = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(ids));
    window.open('/api/sessions/export/sessions?ids='+pars+'&access_token='+Auth.getToken(), '_blank');
}
```

This opens up a new window briefly with the NodeJS API path that then calls the Spring/Hibernate API and pipes the response back as the response to the original request.

The final line of the Node API uses `request` to make the POST request to the Spring/Hibernate server, and pipe the response back via the initial `res` object. Hopefully this helps anybody else looking to pass remote binary files back to the client.